# React Native ListView: Wrong row removed when deleting

Tags: listview, react-native

I know this has been asked before, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424212/listview-removing-wrong-row-on-datasource-update), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351259/how-to-add-delete-item-into-listview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060530/react-native-remove-item-from-listview).

However, none of the answers/comments are satisfactory. They either tell you to clone the data which doesn't solve the problem or to set a unique key on the ListView which solves the problem but creates a new one.

When you set a unique key on the ListView and update it after deletion the entire view renders again and scrolls to the top. A user who scrolls down a list to delete an item expects the list to maintain it's position.

Here's a contrived example, using what I would assume was the correct way of cloning the data:

```js
var ListViewExample = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => {
      r1 !== r2
    }});
    var rows = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3'];
    return {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows),
    };
  },

  _deleteRow() {
    var rows = ['row 1', 'row 3'];
    this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(rows)})
  },

  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._deleteRow}
      style={{height: 60, flex: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1}}>
      <Text>{rowData}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }

});
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkxUw.gif) you can see a gif of it in action where the wrong row get's removed. The alternative, to set the `key` prop of the ListView does remove the correct row but as I said will cause the list to scroll to the top.

**UPDATE**

I've already accepted Nader's answer below but this does not seem to be the right way because it does not call `rowHasChanged` on the dataSource. It also doesn't conform to the ListView documentation. It did solve my problem so I'll leave it marked as the answer but I have the feeling this is a workaround rather than the correct solution

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Okay this is awkward but my `rowHasChanged` function was missing the `return` statement. Too much ES6 sugar in my coffee I guess.

So in conclusion, if you screw up your `rowHasChanged` function, `this._ds` will work for some reason. If you do things the right way to begin with you should probably use something like:

```
this.setState({
  dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(rows)
});
```

when updating your `dataSource`.

Remember also that you need a new `rows` datablob. Mutating it in place with something like `cloneWithRows(rows.push(newRow)` will not work whereas `cloneWithRows(rows.concat([newRow])` will.

Comment: If it helps anyone else... the key for me was making a deep copy of my list before cloning... so before cloneWithRows do new_rows = [...rows]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting your datasource based on the previous ListView.DataSource instance. I've set up a demo of what I am talking about [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/YGBcIA), and put the example below along with another way of doing this.

Try doing this:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ListView
} = React;

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => { r1 !== r2 }});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    var rows = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3'];
    return {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows),
    };
  },

  _deleteRow() {
    var rows = ['row 1', 'row 3'];
    this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows)})
  },

  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._deleteRow}
      style={{height: 60, flex: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1}}>
      <Text>{rowData}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }

});
```

https://rnplay.org/apps/YGBcIA

You can also use rowID in renderRow to identify the item you want to delete, then in your delete function, reset the state of the dataSource.

Check out the example I've set up [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/BJjiMQ). Also, the code is below:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ListView
} = React;

var rows = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3'];
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => {
      r1 !== r2
    }});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {

    return {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      rows: rows
    };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows( this.state.rows )
    })
  },

  _deleteRow(rowID) {
    this.state.rows.splice(rowID, 1)
    this.setState({
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows( this.state.rows ),
    })
  },

  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this._deleteRow(rowID) }
      style={{height: 60, flex: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1}}>
      <Text>{rowData}</Text> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }

});
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 19,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks! The Movie tutorial on the React Native website as well as the documentation for the ListView set the new state the way I did, with `dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows` so I guess I didn't think of doing it your way before. Again, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, yeah the docs on the ListView are ok but they are not their best. I'm working on a pull request at the moment, hopefully they'll think it makes sense!

Comment: I just noticed that using the method you described above, `rowHasChanged` does not get called. You can verify it by putting a console log in there. That can't be the intended behavior, can it? And like I said, the React Native docs update the state with `this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows` rather than with `ds.cloneWithRows` on some global `ds` object.

Comment: Whoops, turns out there was a bug in my original code example. See update above.