# How to update React-Native listview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

I am having strange behavior when a row is being added to my listview. I am not sure where my logic is wrong. I have tabs using react-native-tab-view. On Tab 2 I am adding a object to "Favorites" array that has is being displayed on Tab 4. Before I add the object this is what is being displayed

[image: Before]

After I add the object and go back to Tab 4 this is what I am see

[image: after]

And Code

```
   const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      favoriteDB: props.favorites,
      renderPlaceholder: true,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.favoriteDB),
        renderPlaceholder: false
      })
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps) {
    const {favorites} = this.props

    if (JSON.stringify(favorites) != JSON.stringify(prevProps.favorites)) {
      this._updateFavorites()
    }
  }

  _updateFavorites() {
    const {favorites} = this.props

    this.setState({
      favoriteDB: favorites,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(favorites)
    })
  }

 render() {
    const {dataSource} = this.state
    const {visibleHeight, visibleWidth} = this.props

    if (this.state.renderPlaceholder)
      return <Placeholder/>

    return (
      <Container theme={theme}>
        <View style={{ flex:1, height: visibleHeight - 100, width: visibleWidth }}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <List>
                <ListView
                  style={{ height: visibleHeight - 100, width: visibleWidth }}
                  enableEmptySections={TRUE}
                  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={FALSE}
                  initialListSize={100}
                  pageSize={100}
                  dataSource={dataSource}
                  renderRow={rowData => this._renderRow(rowData)}/>
              </List>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </View>
      </Container>
    )
  }
```

Comment: In _updateFavorites, if you `console.log(favorites)`, are you getting the whole array of items or just the added one?

Comment: @MattAft Suspicious space above `BAKER, MARLENE J`, what's that?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps receives nextProps not prevProps - although the naming wouldn't affect the logic here

Comment: @fumi_hwh  not sure what is exactly happening. maybe the rows are there but not being shown?

Comment: @MattAft Is that `Placeholder `? You could inspect the element.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this adding and removing rows to the input of cloneWithRows with `ListView` as well as the data array for the new `SectionList`.

My workaround is to add a key for ListView that changes when the dataSource changes (name and size worked).

```
   return (
    <SectionList
      key={"mylistview_" + this.props.maps.length}
      style=
   ...
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31481960/7223